# How do we do e2e testing with polymer and selenium?

Tags: testing, polymer

Angular has protractor to listen to lifecycle events in Angular.

eg: `ptor.waitForAngular();`

Is their a way to get selenium tests to wait for the various life-cycle events in polymer?

Currently we can have simple e2e tests running mocha, to do this is embed the tests directly in the html like how they do it in the source code.

You can just run your tests like they do [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/blob/master/test/runner.html).

```
 <script>
      document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
        mocha.run();
      });
    </script>
```

Eg to check for correct updates in a change watcher you can do this:

```
Polymer('x-test', {
            bar: '',
            ready: function() {
              this.bar = 'bar';
              setTimeout(function() {
                this.zonk = 'zonk';
              }.bind(this));
            },
            barChanged: function() {
              chai.assert.equal(this.bar, 'bar', 'change in ready calls *Changed');
              checkDone();
            },
            zonkChanged: function() {
              chai.assert.equal(this.zonk, 'zonk', 'change calls *Changed without prototype value')
              checkDone();
            }
          });
```

and for eg if you wanted to check a computer property is correct after the ready event you can do this:

```
<x-foo foo="mee" bar="too" count=3></x-foo>

    <polymer-element name="x-foo" attributes="foo bar count">
      <template>{{ fooBar }}:{{ fooBarCounted }}</template>
      <script>
        Polymer('x-foo', {
          computed: {
            fooBarCounted: 'repeat(fooBar, count)',
            fooBar: "foo + '-' + bar"
          },
          repeat: function(str, count) {
            var retval = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              retval += (i ? ' ' : '') + str + '(' + i + ')';
            }
            return retval;
          },
          ready: function() {
            chai.assert.equal(this.shadowRoot.innerHTML, 'mee-too:mee-too(0) mee-too(1) mee-too(2)');
            done();
          }
        })
      </script>
    </polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually selenium (and other libs based on on it) can wait elements to appear on the page.

E.g. `browser.waitForExist('#selector')`

See API documentation here http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForExist.html

Hope it might be useful for you.